# XML inner text and formatting

Tags: xml, powershell, visual-studio-code, formatting

I was under the impression that

```
<Element>Text</Element>
```

and

```
<Element>
  Text
</Element>
```

where effectively identical. Both elements contain nothing but a text node. I prefer the former because 99% of the XML I am working with has just a few characters up to a moderately long URL path or the like as the inner text. With a variable `[Xml.XmlElement]$Parent` of the parent element, I have been using dot notation to access the text, with `$Parent.Element` returning `Text`.

Thus far I have been editing PowerShell in the ISE and XML in NotePad++, but I want to step up my game by using VS Code for both. And VS Code automatically formatted my XML the second way. Which then broke all my code.

So, I am wondering what the actual difference is there? Given that NotePad++ and all the online XML validators, plus the .NET XML reader, consider the former formatting to be valid and well formed XML, it seems odd that VS Code would force a different formatting. But I assume there is a reason why it uses the different formatting, but I can't find anything that explains the difference between the two approaches, or the pro's and con's of each.

I suspect the more vertically efficient form I have been using will still be my preference, and I will need to figure out how to get VS Code to allow that, but for now I am just curious what the difference really is, since I was wrong in thinking for years that there was none.

Comment: If VSCode "formats" the XML by converting the first form to the second, then it's plain wrong. A formatter should never do that. Lots of applications are going to break if you add whitespace in places where it's signfiicant.

Comment: This is odd indeed as whitespace in elements which contain text is [significant](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-white-space). I could not reproduce your issue though. My installation of VSCode doesn't automatically reformat XML. Are you using any XML plugin in VSCode?

Comment: @zett42 I didn't think I had anything XML specific installed, but I had installed a bundle of plugins based on an intro to VS Code video, so I'll take a closer look. I am also having some odd problems with Git, so likely I need to deactivate everything, then activate things one at a time and see what breaks.

Answer (score 0):

The two elements in your example are both well formed but are not identical - because of the extra spaces in the second. To test that, place both of them inside a root element and try

```
//Element[1]=//(Element[2])
```

The expression will return a `Boolean='false'`

If you run

```
string-length(//Element[1])
```

you'll get `4` but for

```
string-length(//Element[2])
```

you'll get `8`, for the same reason. Similarly

```
//Element[.="Text"]
```

will return the first, but not the second, while

```
//Element[contains(.,"Text")]
```

will return both.

So long story short, "same, same - but different"...